# VC++ 2010 search listview for a certain string

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, clr

I have a listview created that I am adding data to and I want to avoid duplicates so I am searching the listview before I add the new item to it. I found some similiar code on here (I think?)

```
array<ListViewItem^>^ lvHostsSearch = lvHosts->Items->Find(gcnew String(myStr), false);
if(lvHostsSearch->Length == 0)
{
   // Add Item to listbox since it was not found.
}
```

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page for the Find() method states that the return value is an array:

An array of ListViewItem objects containing the matching items, or an **empty array** if no items matched.

So that is why Its testing for an array of 0 length. Though it still keeps adding it over and over again? I know my logic must be wrong or seeing something wrong with this. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT (SOLVED):**

I ended up FINALLY finding the  way to search for text in a listview. As viewed on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page for it. I ended up doing something like:

```
if(myListView->FindItemWithText(myStr) == nullptr)
```

Hope it might help someone else out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using ListView::FindItemWithText, read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on its use. Refer to my edit above for how I solved my exact issue.